# Accessing MultiLevel Nested Children in Firebase Database Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Realtime Database.

I have a customer id which corresponds to customer table. I need to fetch its respective apartment name. Then search the record having same apartment name in apartment table. Once found, I need to get all serviceType values from its respective segments. Also need to fetch its block from apartment table.

Table structure is as follows:

```
customer
  -L1x2AKUL_KNTKXyza
    apartment_name:"ABC Residency"


appartment
  -L1Ohec4nW-ya_SkiG49
    apartment_name:"ABC Residency"
    block: "A Wing"
    segments
      -L1OhecGtEk_8xdNs67T
        serviceType:"Mopping"
      -L1OhecGtEk_8xdNs631
        serviceType:"Cleaning"
```

I want to use only one firebase database reference object and achieve this multilevel access.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you storing apartment_name in customer table? You should store the reference of appartment. That will solve the problem of searching.

Comment: I have not designed the DB. This is the expected functionality and cannot modify DB at all

Comment: This question is a basic Firebase observe and then a query; observeSingleEvent on node *-L1x2A* to then get the apartment_name and then perform a query on the *apartment* node for that name - this is covered right in the Firebase Getting Started Guide [Working With Lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data). Is there a specific issue that you're having? Can you show your code and let us know where the issue is?

Comment: I am creating multiple DatabaseReference objects nested one within the other. Is there any way to optimize this to achieve the above?

Comment: Moreover, I got upto apartment name filtering. But unable to get that apartment's segments. this is the code :
Database.database().reference()
                        .child("appartment")
                        .queryOrdered(byChild: "appartment_name")
                        .queryEqual(toValue: apartmentName)
                        .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

Comment: Please update your question with code. Don't put it in comments as it's really hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you. I've created a class called `CRUD` to perform all of my firebase functions.

```
import Firebase

/**
 CRUD Object to maintain Firebase DB
 - MUST use crud.creatRef() before any save or read functions!!
 */
class CRUD: NSObject {
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var id: String!

    /**Create FirebaseDB reference for use of CRUD Object to interact with DB*/
    func createRef() {
        id = PageDataSource.sharedInstance.myID!
        ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://yourURL.firebaseio.com/")
    }

}
```

When calling `CRUD` to save or load data within my app I have to do this:

```
let crud = CRUD()
crud.createRef()
crud.doSomething()
```

I've had great success with this. You'll need to design your model and implement the rest of the code accordingly. When you create your save functions they should go inside of the `CRUD` object.